# Error "nil requires a contextual type" using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

I'd like to achieve the following in code:

```
class MyService {

    let mySubject = BehaviorSubject<MyData>(value: nil)

    //....

}
```

Unfortunately, I get the "nil requires a contextual type" error. I want the subject to be "empty" till I actually put something in there. How can I pass nil as the argument then? Can I cast it to my own type to make it work?

Comment: can you show `BehaviorSubject` declaration?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the [reference for RxSwift `BehaviorSubject`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxSwift/3.0.0-rc.1/Classes/BehaviorSubject.html#/s:FC7RxSwift15BehaviorSubjectcFT5valuex_GS0_x_), the `init(value:)` initializer is declared as

> ```
> public init(value: Element)
> ```

Where the `value` parameter is described as:

> **`value`**
>
> Initial value sent to observers when no other value has been received
>   by the subject yet.

And where `Element` is the placeholder type of `BehaviorSubject`:

> ```
> public final class BehaviorSubject<Element> ...
> ```

This means you need to specify the placeholder type `Element` as an `Optional` type if you are to be able to set the initial value (used when no other value has been received) to `nil`. E.g.:

```
class MyService {

    let mySubject = BehaviorSubject<MyData?>(value: nil)

    //....
}
```

Or, letting the compiler infer the placeholder as `MyData?` by using the non-sugared `.none` form for the `nil` argument:

```
class MyService {

    let mySubject = BehaviorSubject(value: Optional<MyData>.none)

    //....
}
```

---

As for understanding the actual error message better, consider the following self-contained example:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    init(value: T) {}
}

struct Bar {}

let bar = Bar()

_ = Foo<Bar>(value: bar)           // OK
_ = Foo(value: bar)                // OK, T inferred as Bar
_ = Foo<Bar>(value: nil)           // Error: error: 'nil' requires a contextual type
_ = Foo<Bar?>(value: nil)          // OK
_ = Foo(value: Optional<Bar>.none) // OK, T inferred as Bar?
```

Answer (score 2):

While [dfri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465089/swift-nil-requires-a-contextual-type/51465238#51465238) is technically correct, you might want to consider a different type when working with RxSwift. Since you want your subject to be empty only at the beginning, I'd suggest to use `ReplaySubject` or `PublishSubject`.

A similar question has also been asked on RxSwift's GitHub issue page. [Allow BehaviorSubject without initial value](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1038). There, kzaher suggests the `ReplaySubject`.

Your subject would then look like this, without any initial value and without MyData being `Optional`.

```
let subject = ReplaySubject<MyData>().create(bufferSize: 1)
```

Comment: Correct code is: let subject = ReplaySubject<MyData>.create(bufferSize: 1)